# Combining function parameter with a like_regex function in postgres when searching jsonb GIN index

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I am trying to do a case-insensitive partial search (contains string) on a property value - stored in a jsonb field in postgres.

The search is looking for a value within the **title** column of table destination which has an array of elements as follows:

```
[{"key": "EN", "text":"london and milk"},{"key": "FR", "text":"Edinburgh with milk and honey"}]
```

I have created a GIN index on the **title** field and a function to deal with the search.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search(query_string character varying)   
    RETURNS SETOF destination 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'  
AS $BODY$
begin
return query select *
from destination
--where title @? '$.* ? (@ like_regex ' || query_string || ' flag "i")';
where title @? '$.* ? (@ like_regex ".*milk.*" flag "i")';
end;
$BODY$;
```

So the function works nicely if the regexp string is hardcoded (as shown above), but the search should be based on the incoming **query_string**.  The commented line in the function shows an attempt to try to include the parameter in the query. (this will result in unterminated string constant error)

1. How can I exchange the hard-coded **milk** to parameter **search_query**?
2. Are there other (simpler) ways that would yield the same end result?

Comment: You mention the GIN index, but a GIN index on jsonb is not actually helpful here.  It will scan the whole table anyway.  If forced to use the index anyway, it will use the index to list every row in the table, then scan the table via that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is one of precedence.  `@?` and '||' are tied and are processed left to right, so you are applying `@?` to only a fragment of the string not the completely built string.  Then you are trying to concat things to the Boolean result of `@?`.  You can fix this by constructing the string inside parentheses.  A side affect of this is that you then have to cast it to jsonpath explicitly.

```
where title @? ( '$.* ? (@ like_regex "' || query_string || '" flag "i")' )::jsonpath;
```

But I think it would be cleaner to construct the jsonpath in a variable, rather than on the fly in the query itself.  Could someone inject something into the jsonpath string that could do something nasty?  I don't know enough about jsonpath to rule that out.

(code part of the suggested solution edited by question author to include the double quotes missing - see comment)

Comment: Thank you!! Your solution worked except for missing double quotes to encapsulate the query_string.   With out them you get: 

'ERROR:  syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P, expecting STRING_P at or near " " of jsonpath input'

With that minor edit the solution is: 
'where title @? ('$.* ? (@ like_regex "' || query_string || '" flag "i")')::jsonpath;'